# Apache Zeppelin build fails at Apache Geode interpreter phase, return code 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, geode

currently new to the whole Ubuntu/Maven/hadoop/spark/zeppelin stuff and been stuck for a while in the zeppelin install. Could someone give me a hand with this? This is also my first post on stack overflow so let me know if i can improve the content of this question in any way to make it more accessible. Thanks

Problem:
Apache Zeppelin install in Ubuntu fails at phase Apache Geode interpreter

Current installed versions:
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
- Spark 1.5.1
- Hadoop 2.6.0
- Maven 3.0.5
- Java 1.7.0_79
- Zeppelin (latest from GIT)

Call in terminal (as a non-root user):

```
sudo mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.5.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0
```

Output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zeppelin .......................................... SUCCESS [10:16.733s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter ............................. SUCCESS [56.534s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine ................................. SUCCESS [5.153s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ...................... SUCCESS [24.264s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark ................................... SUCCESS [32.938s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter .................... SUCCESS [1.532s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [1.427s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [1.423s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [2.756s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Phoenix Interpreter .............. SUCCESS [6.107s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Geode interpreter ................ FAILURE [0.485s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Cassandra ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:30.506s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Oct 10 00:35:05 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 120M/652M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project zeppelin-geode: Failed to resolve dependencies for one or more projects in the reactor. Reason: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.geode:gemfire-json:jar:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Failed to retrieve POM for org.apache.geode:gemfire-json:jar:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.apache.geode:gemfire-json:pom:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT from http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ext-release-local has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.geode:gemfire-json:pom:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT from/to ext-release-local (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/org/apache/geode/gemfire-json/1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/gemfire-json-1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict.
[ERROR] org.apache.geode:gemfire-json:jar:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] spring-release (https://repo.spring.io/release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] spring-snapshot (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] libs-release (http://repo.spring.io/libs-release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] ext-release-local (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-geode:jar:0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2) org.apache.geode:gemfire-core:jar:1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-geode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new day with a fresh cup of coffee and a laptop reboot apparently fixed the problem.